# How to batch in Pytorch Geometric temporal

Tags: pytorch, lstm, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I'm working with pytorch geometric temporal, my dataset consist in a sequence of human keypoints to determine an action. Each batch have 16 sequences/videos, each sequence have 84 frames and each frame have 17 keypoints, each keypoints have 3 coordinates (X, Y, probability).

So my final shape is: 16, 84, 17, 3

What I don't know now is how to do he training loop. Without batch the following code works for me:

```
### TRAIN
model.train()

loss_history = []
for _ in tqdm(range(epochs)):
    h, c = None, None
    total_loss = 0
    for i, batch in enumerate(train_dataset):
        for window in sample:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            
            y_pred, H, C = model(window, h, c)
            print(y_pred)

            h = H[stride-1]
            c = C[stride-1]
            
            assert y_pred.shape == window.y.shape
            loss = torch.mean((y_pred - window.y)**2)
            total_loss += loss.item()
            
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
    total_loss /= i+1
    loss_history.append(total_loss)
```

But don't know how to include the batch here, any ideas?

Thanks!